# Property not known: "charset". --> schema.prisma:12

Tags: sql, mysql, prisma

```
datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
  config   = {
    charset   = "utf8mb4"
    collation = "utf8mb4_unicode_ci"
  }
}
```

i am getting the error on running npx prisma migrate dev --name initial --preview-feature

```
error: Error validating: This line is invalid. It does not start with any known Prisma schema keyword.
  -->  schema.prisma:15
   | 
14 |   }
15 | }
16 | model User {
   | 
error: Property not known: "charset".
  -->  schema.prisma:12
```